# ORACLE SQL Retrieving records from 1 table based on values from other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables:

-Table: Periods - Fields: Period_ID, Member_name, Start_time, Finish_time, Period_Timeouts

-Table: PeriodTimeouts - Fields: Timeout_ID, Period_ID, Start_time, Finish_time

-Table: Timeouts - Fields: Timeout_ID, Start_time, Finish_time, Member_name

The only link between them is as follows:

-A Periods record may contain 0 or more PeriodTimeouts. So a record in Periods will contain 0 or several Timeout_IDs in its Period_Timeouts field.

-Each PeriodTimeouts record has the ID of the Period it is linked to and the ID of the Timeouts record it represents.

I need to find all Periods that don't have any PeriodTimeouts but for which there exists a Timeouts record, that falls within the same time range, and applies to the same Member_name.

Note the time range of a Periods record or a Timeouts record doesn't have to be the same, if any part of the Timeouts record time range falls within the time range of the Periods record then that counts.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
  PERIODS.PERIOD_ID,
  PERIODS.MEMBER_NAME,
  PERIODS.START_TIME,
  PERIODS.FINISH_TIME
FROM
  PERIODS,
  PERIODTIMEOUTS
WHERE
  PERIODS.PERIOD_ID=PERIODTIMEOUTS.PERIOD_ID(+)
  AND  
  PERIODS.FINISH_TIME  <  '2014-10-09 00:00:00'
  AND
  PERIODS.FINISH_TIME  >=  '2014-10-08 00:00:00'
  AND
  (SELECT COUNT(TIMEOUTS.TIMEOUT_ID) FROM TIMEOUTS
     WHERE
        TIMEOUTS.MEMBER_NAME = PERIODS.MEMBER_NAME AND
        TIMEOUTS.FINISH_TIME >= PERIODS.START_TIME AND
        TIMEOUTS.START_TIME <= PERIODS.FINISH_TIME) > 0
```

But the query takes so long to execute that I don't think it's working (I've waited to about 10 minutes and it was still processing) but mind you the tables have a lot of data. There are about 2000 Periods every day and the data goes back about 3 years.

**Example data:**

PERIODS(PERIODS_ID, MEMBER_NAME, START_TIME, FINISH_TIME)

1, DTW234, 2014-10-09 01:05:54, 2014-10-09 01:15:54

2, DTX432, 2014-10-09 01:25:32, 2014-10-09 02:15:51

3, DTW211, 2014-10-09 01:34:43, 2014-10-09 01:36:42

4, DTW002, 2014-10-09 01:45:12, 2014-10-09 03:54:45

PERIODTIMEOUTS(TIMEOUT_ID, PERIOD_ID, START_TIME, FINISH_TIME)

3, 1, 2014-10-09 00:01:36, 2014-10-09 01:06:27

4, 4, 2014-10-09 01:50:01, 2014-10-09 02:32:38

TIMEOUTS(TIMEOUT_ID, MEMBER_NAME, START_TIME, FINISH_TIME)

1, DTX432, 2014-10-08 23:01:35, 2014-10-09 01:26:17

2, DTW211, 2014-10-08 20:21:52, 2014-10-09 01:00:17

3, DTW234, 2014-10-09 00:01:36, 2014-10-09 01:06:27

4, DTW002, 2014-10-09 01:50:01, 2014-10-09 02:32:38

**Expected result**

1, DTW234, 2014-10-09 01:05:54, 2014-10-09 01:15:54

**Explanation of results**

- The result should be records from the Periods table.
- Period 1 is the only Period for which there is a Timeouts record (Timeout 3) where the Member_name is the same, the time range of the TIMEOUTcovers some of the time range of the PERIOD and there is no PERIODTIMEOUTS record for the TIMEOUT.
- Period 3 is not included in the results because although it doesn't have any matching records in the PERIODTIMEOUTS, there is no TIMEOUT whose time range covers some of the PERIOD time range.

Comment: Why do you think this needs PL/SQL instead of a straight SQL query?  What have you tried?

Comment: The database is Oracle based, I assumed that meant I had to use PL/SQL? I don't really know much about that side of things.

I haven't been able to try anything as I can't think of a way to get what I'm after in a query

Comment: @RichardMaguire could you put together a small sample of data from each table and your expected result based on that sample?

Comment: Well, what is "a lot of data?"  Do you have the proper indexes available?  Have you run an explain plan?

Comment: Hi, I've added some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select p.period_id,
       p.member_name,
       p.start_time,
       p.finish_time,
       count(*) as num_timeouts
  from periods p
  join timeouts t
    on p.member_name = t.member_name
   and t.finish_time >= p.start_time
   and t.start_time <= p.finish_time
  left join periodtimeouts pt
    on p.period_id = pt.period_id
 where p.finish_time < '2014-10-09 00:00:00'
   and p.finish_time >= '2014-10-08 00:00:00'
   and pt.period_id is null
 group by p.period_id, p.member_name, p.start_time, p.finish_time
```